# Java Property File in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, properties

Is it possible to implement the properties file in a database table?

Comment: why do you want to keep it in db?

Comment: @Nandkumar : My project uses MySQL database and I would like to implement properties based on user selection, either as a file or as a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly.

You can use JavaDB for this, SQL lite, MySQL etc. It is really easy to bind too.

Here are some sample projects:

http://pure-essence.net/2011/02/10/spring-loading-properties-from-database-with-a-twist/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28893/Loading-Application-Properties-from-a-Database